# Count total number of points inside of polygon in PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two different tables. One is called stores (points) and another called county_grid(multipolygon).  I want to return the total number of points per grid and later place the results as a column into the polygon(stores) table.
This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT county_grid.gid, count(*) AS totale FROM stores, county_grid WHERE 
ST_intersects(county_grid.geom, stores.geom) GROUP BY county_grid.gid.
```

This retrieves 0 rows however.  Both geoms are set to srid 4326.

Comment: This query should work. Apparently none of your points are contained in a polygon. Please add some sample data to the question

Comment: You're correct, Tommaso.  It worked after I created a spatial index for the stores table.  Rookie mistake.  Thank you for taking your time to reply to this post though.